# Tidying up variables for dynamic objects

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables, global-variables

I currently use a variety of objects which are dynamically created in my form. Due to being dynamically created the objects have to be declared before they are made. This leaves me with a long list of variables which really fill up my data dictionary in my project write up.

I have included the list of variables below. Is there a way that I could tidy this up, for example in a structure?

Also because they are public variables I'm wondering if this code is very inefficient and how I could improve it.

```
Public lblanswer As Label
Public txtQuestions(Qnum) As TextBox
Public lblQnumber(Qnum) As Label
Public cboQuestionType(Qnum) As ComboBox
Public txtMultichoice(Qnum * 4) As TextBox
Public txtShortAnswer(Qnum) As TextBox
Public btnTrue(Qnum), btnFalse(Qnum) As Button
Public btnSaveQuestions As Button
Public lblFileName As Label
Public txtFileName As TextBox
Public lblQType(Qnum) As Label
Public txtanswer(Qnum) As TextBox
Public truecheckbox(Qnum) As CheckBox
Public falsecheckbox(Qnum) As CheckBox
Public tickIcon, crossIcon As PictureBox
Public optTrue(Qnum), optFalse(Qnum) As RadioButton
Public grpTrueFalse(Qnum) As GroupBox
Public lblABCD(Qnum * 4) As Label
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you dynamically creating it from and why? At first glance, it doesn't seem like you need different types of objects. For example, you have true and false checkboxes but that should be a radio button. Your text boxes are different for a reason?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. You are correct about the radiobuttons and I have changed that now. However I have a lot of different text boxes being created - some used for entering the text for a question and some for where the teacher writes in the answer to the question.

Comment: I think I created an array of Object and created each one and added it to an array. If it is a unique object, you have to create it uniquely. You could create generic text boxes if you had another way to track them, but you're probably best to leave what you have. If you had the same objects you could use a loop, but unique objects need to be unique.